# Deploying asp.net mvc web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deploying

I have asp.net mvc web site. When i want to change some code in controller i need to build all the site and upload it to the server. Is there some merhods when i need just copy controller file by ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .cs files that contain the controllers are compiled into dll files, so at the very least you have to upload a new set of dlls.

The views defined in the .aspx files are a different story.  You can make changes in the .aspx files without rebuilding the entire site.